# PyQt5: cannot write cookie to file using QFile

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5, qfile, qtextstream

I have a file named *cookies.txt*.

```
fd = QFile(":/cookies.txt")
available_cookies = QtNetwork.QNetworkCookieJar().allCookies()
for cookie in available_cookies:
   print(cookie.toRawForm(1))
   QTextStream(cookie.toRawForm(1), fd.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly))
fd.close()
```

Here is my full traceback:

```
QTextStream(cookie.toRawForm(1),        fd.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly))
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
QTextStream(): too many arguments
QTextStream(QIODevice): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QByteArray'
QTextStream(QByteArray, mode: Union[QIODevice.OpenMode,    QIODevice.OpenModeFlag] = QIODevice.ReadWrite): argument 2 has unexpected type 'bool'
```

I am following the C++ documentation, and I am having trouble writing the corresponding python syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really trying to write to a resource path? Resources are read-only, so that is not going to work.

To write to a non-resource path:

```
fd = QFile('/tmp/cookies.txt')
if fd.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly):
    available_cookies = QtNetwork.QNetworkCookieJar().allCookies()
    stream = QTextStream(fd)
    for cookie in available_cookies:
        data = cookie.toRawForm(QtNetwork.QNetworkCookie.Full)
        stream << data
    fd.close()
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know that :/ represents resource path. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In `QTextStream(cookie.toRawForm(1), fd.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly))`, you pass 2 arguments, a `QByteArray`, and a `bool` (`QIODevice::open` returns a boolean), but `QTextStream` cannot take a `QByteArray` with a `bool`.